# Calculating a number from items in an array then getting the sum of those numbers with Array.prototype.reduce()? (Javascipt)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've been asked in an exercise to find out how many years did all the inventors live in one number using "Array.prototype.reduce()"

```
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];
```

So far I've come to this which lists each age individually but now I'm unsure how to actually add the numbers up to return as 1 integer.

```
console.log("Exercise 5:")
const totalYears = inventors.reduce((acc, inventor) => {
  let age = inventor.passed - inventor.year

  acc[`${inventor.first} ${inventor.last}`] = age
  return acc
}, {})
console.log(totalYears)
```

Any help would be fantastic, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acc` should be a number representing the total years:

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
]; 

const totalYears = inventors.reduce((acc, inventor) => 
  acc + (inventor.passed - inventor.year)
, 0);

console.log(totalYears)
```